# Delphi : SSL routines:SSL3_GET_RECORD:wrong version number

Tags: delphi, ssl, indy, indy10, ftps

I found several topics about the same problem but it didn't help me to resolve my problem.

I'm trying to connect to a FTPS server (with Delphi 10.3) using this code:

```pascal
IdSSLIOHandler := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create(nil);
IdSSLIOHandler.SSLOptions.Method := sslvSSLv3;
IdSSLIOHandler.SSLOptions.SSLVersions := [sslvSSLv2, sslvSSLv23, sslvSSLv3, sslvTLSv1,sslvTLSv1_1,sslvTLSv1_2];
IdFTP.IOHandler := IdSSLIOHandler;
IdFtp.UseTLS := utUseExplicitTLS;
IdFtp.DataPortProtection := ftpdpsPrivate;
IdFtp.Connect();
```

I put several versions of `SSLVersions` in the array to be sure to have the good one.

I got this message when `TIdFTP` tries to connect:

> SSL routines:SSL3_GET_RECORD:wrong version number

When I try to connect with FileZilla, it works and the protocol seems to be TLS 1.2.

Do you have any advice?

Comment: `sslvSSLv2, sslvSSLv23, sslvSSLv3` should not be used anymore as they are heavily insecure. When those options are enabled the client sends an SSLv3 request which most server no longer support.

Comment: Thanks ! That was perfect !

Comment: Also, don't set `SSLOptions.Method` manually at all. It is deprecated, set only the `SSLOptions.SSLVersions`, it will update the `Method` accordingly.

Comment: It's good to know.