# I can not fix Error SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol

Tags: delphi, https, openssl, tls1.2, indy

I try to get page content of website 'https://www.whiskyauctioneer.com' by using Indy components for Delphi. I'm using Delphi X7 and Indy 10.6.2.0 and dlls from openssl-1.0.2u

I think since this website using TLS 1.2 my code isn't working anymore.

I tried different methods with errors:

```
error:1408F10B:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_RECORD:wrong version number
```

or

```
error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol
```

My Code:

```
procedure TFormMain.Button21Click(Sender: TObject);
const
  url = 'https://www.whiskyauctioneer.com';
var
  lHTTP: TIdHTTP;
  lIOHandler: TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL;
begin

    IdHTTP1 := TIdHTTP.Create( self );
    IdHTTP1.Request.UserAgent := 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:12.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/12.0';
    lIOHandler := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create( IdHTTP1 );

    lIOHandler.SSLOptions.Method := sslvTLSv1_2;
    IdHTTP1.IOHandler := lIOHandler;

    showmessage(IdHTTP1.Get(url));
end;
```

I hope somebody can point me into the right direction.

Comment: As indicated in Remy's comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61478573/delphi-ssl-routinesssl3-get-recordwrong-version-number), try setting `SSLOptions.SSLVersions` instead of `SSLOptions.Method`.

Comment: Thank you for your fast reply! Unfortunately if I change to     `lIOHandler.SSLOptions.SSLVersions := [sslvTLSv1_2];` it is the same result `error:1408F10B:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_RECORD:wrong version number`

Comment: Are you use builtin Indy version or take it from [github](https://github.com/IndySockets/Indy)? Your code with Delphi 10.3.3 and builtin Indy 10.6.2.5366 works fine. I have only replace `IdHTTP1` with `lHTTP` in your example.

Comment: I use latest github version and changed use of `SSLOptions.Method` to `SSLOption.SSLVersions` as @Olivier told. I tried Delphi 10.3.3 Community Edition but also get an error `error:1409442E:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:tlsv1 alert protocol version`. I'm wondering because error message tells "tlsv1". You are right `IdHTTP1` have to be replaced by `lHTTP`.

Comment: Did you put openssl dll's near your exe?

Comment: Thx that helped to get it running in Delphi 10.3. Does anybody has a tip why it is not working in XE7? I'm getting following error there: `error:1408F10B:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_RECORD:wrong version number`

Comment: @Hanswurst Are you SURE the website in question uses TLS 1.2? Because you are *forcing* Indy to use TLS 1.2 *exclusively*. For wider flexibility with multiple sites, you should generally set `SSLVersions := [sslvTLSv1, sslvTLSv1_1, sslvTLSv1_2]` instead. Also, when the error occurs, what do Indy's `IsOpenSSL_TLSv1_1_Available()` and `IsOpenSSL_TLSv1_2_Available()` functions in the `IdSSLOpenSSLHeaders` unit return? If TLS 1.1 and 1.2 are not available in the OpenSSL DLLs, Indy will silently fallback to TLS 1.0. Where did you get your DLLs from exactly?

Comment: @zed "*Did you put openssl dll's near your exe?*" - although putting the DLLs in the same folder as the EXE is preferred, you can alternatively use Indy's `IdOpenSSLSetLibPath()` function in the `IdSSLOpenSSLHeaders` unit to tell Indy where the DLLs are located.

Comment: When I open the website in firefox an click on safety detail firefox shows me that the connection is encrypted with 128Bit Key TLS 1.2. I changed SSLVersions to `[sslvTLSv1, sslvTLSv1_1, sslvTLSv1_2]` as you told. The eror message changes to `error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol`. I took the dlls from `https://indy.fulgan.com/SSL/openssl-1.0.2u-i386-win32.zip`. I don't know how to exactly call the function `IsOpenSSL_TLSv1_1_Available` to give you the information you asked for.

Comment: XE7 not working because it use an old Indy version.

Comment: @zed Do you mean XE7 with standard components or at all? I thought I can enable new functionality with the latest indy version or am I wrong?

Comment: Of course if you update your indy to the latest version XE7 will work. Even Delphi 2007 work with it. The question is how do you update indy in your XE7 and whether you did it correctly. It's simple, when you correctly update indy in your Delphi, then you will be able to compile and run your example without errors.

Comment: Hello again. What is the correct way to update Indy in Delphi XE7?

I removed "Indy 10 Core Design Time" and "Indy 10 Protocols Design Time" packages from package explorer.

I downloaded the latest updates from git repository https://github.com/IndySockets/Indy.git and created .bpl files. Then I added these .bpl files in package explorer.

I also downloaded the latest ssleay32.dll and libeay32.dll and copied them to the folder where the exe file of my project is generated. I checked with process explorer if the correct dlls are loaded.